# Detailed instructions on running maven built resteasy project from inside eclipse's tomcat server?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, maven, jax-rs

I could use some detailed instructions on how to do this.
By "this", I mean that I have a maven pom.xml, and I have installed it. 
The project uses resteasy and is a simple jax-rs webservice. 
Now I simply want to run it using the tomcat server that I have in Eclipse.
I don't want to have to copy the .war file to my tomcat's webapps directory, and then launch firefox separately.  I can get the index.jsp working from inside Eclipse, but I can not get the actual service to work.  I can get the entire project working when I just manually copy the .war inside tomcat's webapps directory and launch from the command line.

All tutorials are inadequate for me so far, as they assume alot of prior knowledge or are out of date due to dated repositories or inexplicable quirks in with the combo if eclipse, maven, tomcat 7.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following approach:

- In the Tomcat server settings, go to the *Modules* tab
- Add the project's `target/artifact-version` folder as an *External Web Module* - this folder contains the content of the WAR file.
- Use Eclipse's *Servers* view to start/stop Tomcat.

Then compile the project either from command line or through Eclipse's *MavenBuilder*.

If you're using a dynamic web project, you might want to install the *m2e-wtp* module in addition to just *m2e*.